# IE Form Submit Empty yet works with type=checkbox

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, razor

I've looked at dozens of similar questions already but most solutions implement hidden inputs or extensive javascript and none have answered why one type of input works and the other doesn't.

This problem is specific to Internet Explorer, works on both Chrome and FF.

Here's my code to create the form:

```
@foreach (hello.Data.Models.Button btn in Model.Content.Buttons.OrderBy(b => b.Action))
    {
        if (btn.Action == "Close Message" && (Model.SurveyAuditExists == true || Model.SurveyContent == null))
        {                                
             <li class="response-button-item">
                 <input type="submit" class="response-button" name="@btn.Text" id="@btn.Text" onclick="submitForm.submit();" value="@hello.Biz.Helpers.ExtensionMethods.TrimString(btn.Text, new char[] { '&' })" />                                                                
             </li>
         }
```

And here's an example of the resulting HTML:

```
<form id="submitForm" action="/Go/Here/39354" method="post">  
      <ul id="response-button-list">             
          <li class="response-button-item">
              <input name="&amp;Agree" class="response-button" id="&amp;Agree" onclick="submitForm.submit();" type="submit" value="Agree">                                                                
          </li>
          <li class="response-button-item">
               <input name="&amp;Disagree" class="response-button" id="&amp;Disagree" onclick="submitForm.submit();" type="submit" value="Disagree">                                                                
          </li>
      </ul>
```

So when I click either Agree or Disagree on Chrome/FF it returns whether the user has Agreed or Disagreed but in IE it returns blank and results in an error as FormCollection and AllKeys are empty in my controller.

Changing the input type to checkbox and clicking on the box works and submits correctly in IE.

I haven't got nested forms in the page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have a `<input type="submit" ..` and then add `onclick="submitForm.submit();`? And just give you inputs the same `name` attribute (e.g. `name="Action"` so that you can just check the value of `"Action"` in the post method (preferably by adding a parameter `string Action` in the method - its value will be either "Agree" or "Disagree" depending on which button was clicked)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Removing that onclick solved the issue. That was being used for the checkboxes but obviously wasn't needed if input type was submit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @stephenmuecke 's comment I tested the buttons without the JavaScript

> onclick="submitForm.submit();"

As obviously this was competing with the input type="submit", removing the onclick attribute solved any issues.

So in the end the error was all my fault, hopefully this info helps someone else notice this quicker than I did.